# Scroll-Snap-Align: Bug in Chrome & Edge: Gap emerges on page top & bottom

Tags: css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, scroll-snap

I'm trying to create a page with sections which snap always to fullscreen. I use the CSS approach of scroll-snap-align.

The bug: When scrolling upwards on top of the page, or downwards on the bottom of the page, a gap emerges. This gap get's bigger the more you try scrolling upwards / downwards. This bug only appears in Edge and Chrome, not in Safari and Firefox.

See the example here: Green is the html background and black the first scroll section after scrolling upwards four times.

[image]

Here's the code to try out:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Scroll Snap Align</title>
    <style>
        html, body, section {
            margin: 0;
        }
        html {
            scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
            background: greenyellow;
        }
        body {
            height: 100vh;
            overflow: scroll;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
        section {
            scroll-snap-align: start;
            padding: 1rem;
            height: 100vh;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="first" style="background: black; color: white">
            Section 1
        </section>
        <section class="after" style="background: yellow">
            Section 2
        </section>
        <section class="after" style="background: orange">
            Section 3
        </section>
        <section class="last" style="background: orangered">
            Section 4
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm very thankful for solution ideas or comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a common issue on MacOS Edge/Chrome. All you have to do is tell the browser not to overscroll on this page:

```
body {
    overscroll-behavior-y: none;
}
```

Comment: Hey Kendrick, this is just perfect and solved the problem. Thank you a lot!